# Not getting date-time in specific format in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

What I'm trying is

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(NOW(), 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.US');
```

Actual Output:

```
           to_char            
------------------------------
 2021-06-17THH24:05:19.815403
```

but my Expected output:

```
           to_char            
------------------------------
 2021-06-17T06:05:19.815403
```

here When I use `T` then hour print like `HH24`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing the `T` between double quotes:

```
SELECT to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.US');
          to_char           
----------------------------
 2021-06-17T08:11:11.913287
```

Comment: one more thing, what does `T` represent in the datetime  and what is `US`?

Comment: @GT `T` is a string you've chosen and `US` means microsecond (000000-999999). Check this tutorial: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-to_char/

Comment: So there is no specific meaning of `T`. Thank you

Comment: @GT well, at least I'm not aware of `T` and the `to_char` tutorial does not mention it. But I cannot speak for the whole standard :) cheers and happy coding.